# How to read impure text in Python?

Tags: python, codec, text-processing, robustness

Python is very picky about its text codecs.  Unfortunately, anything can and will happen in text, foreign words and line noise being prime examples.  When that happens, I can't have my production system display an error and stop.  What's a good failsafe approach?  Is there a method or library I can use to, for example, simply ignore anything that the codec doesn't recognize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `errors` parameter of [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).  It defaults to `'strict'` which throws exceptions, but `'ignore'` and `'replace'` are some [other options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `except`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s='eëeéeę'

try:
    a=s.decode('ascii')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # handle the error appropriately...
    # this is just an example:
    a='cant decode "s"'
```